# Content Providers, Authority and URI matching

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've been trying to work on a custom content provider and I have a few questions.

1. How is the Android framework using Authority property? Why is it required to declare it in the manifest, shouldn't the class name be enough?
2. Who/what process calls the getType() method in the ContentProvider implementation?
3. What is the need of the urimatcher? Should it be used if the underlying database has only a handful of tables?

Answer (score 1):

You are required to declare it in the manifest because data access permissions are listed in the Market entry.  I.E. "Has permission to read contact information".

`getType()` is called when you want to get the MIMETYPE of a column accessed by a `ContentProvider.`  This is called when you use `MyContentProvider.getType(myUri)`

Hope this helps!