# android content provider AUTHORITIES

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, authority

What is the reason for content provider authorities?

How/why do I want to use them other than I HAVE to declare them in the manifest?

I've tried to do my homework on this question and cannot find a decent, cohesive discussion on this topic.
Here is the best I could find (in additi  on to the four books on Android development I own):

1. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=content+provider+authority
2. [Content Providers, Authority and and URI matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044893/content-providers-authority-and-and-uri-matching)
3. [Get a list of available Content Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001590/get-a-list-of-available-content-providers)
4. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html
5. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Comment: its used to identify particular provider e. g.  content://your.authority

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Authority is used to interact with a particular content provider, that means it must be unique. That's why is a [good practice](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI) to declare it as your domain name (in reverse) plus the name of the package containing the provider, that way is less  likely that other developer creates an app with a content provider declaring the same authority.

You declare it in the manifest so your app and other apps (if you let them) can manipulate
data through your content provider in the form of a uri:

```
content://authority-name/data-in-the-provider
```

It works similar to domains in http urls:

```
http://domain-name/data-in-the-site
```

Comment: so does that mean if I have multiple providers in my app each should be in its own package?

Comment: The authorities need to be unique for each content provider

Comment: Simple and yet powerful explanation without any bunch of bla bla code.

Answer (score 3):

I am also looking for explanation and to add to answer provided by ILovemyPoncho, I hit this particular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536478/why-in-the-android-developer-guide-the-androidauthorities-is-defined-like-this) and I quote:

> > and what exactly is android:authorities asking for?
>
> A system wide unique identifier for your provider. Or better worldwide
>   unique. All providers are registered with the system and they need to
>   be unique or the second app that wants to use the same name can't be
>   installed.
>
> You use that string in the end to communicate with your provider via
>   an Uri like
>
> Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + "your.authoritiy.string")

Let's put it this way: There is an invisible hand that facilitates your request to your app's ContentProvider.

For example:

```
    Uri uri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(NotifireContentProvider2.NOTE_URI, values);
```

Basically, what you are saying here to the Android OS is insert data given the URI containing the authority you have defined in the XML. The OS will search for this particular content provider and send the request to it. You `insert` method on the ContentProvider will be called and you must match the URI to handle it accordingly.

Also, what if, you're content provider is so simplistic that others have similar authority as well. I haven't encountered those two problem I mentioned but I reckon it won't be pleasant.

Authority is there to make sure that the OS understand which provider will provide the data to the requesting app and to make sure that is the provider providing it.